# Drawable folder in Android Studio is empty

Tags: android, android-studio

I started learning android App development from android developer's site.And so I'm using Android Studio.While doing [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html),somehow i got know that my app's `targetSdkVersion` is 22 and `minSdkVersion` is 14.As I don't see "uses-sdk ... "line, I have added it to AndroidManifest XML file.After that I proceeded to [next tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) where I could not see any image files in `drawable` folder. I've tried with other solutions like changing into project view, changing deprecated `ActionBarActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` etc.
In short, I see empty `drawable` folder which should not be.

Comment: well did you put any images in your drawable folder?

Answer (score 3):

> As I don't see "uses-sdk ... "line, I have added it to AndroidManifest XML file

The `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`, for a typical Android Studio project, are defined in `app/build.gradle`, which is why you did not see a `<uses-sdk>` element in the manifest.

> I see empty drawable folder which should not be.

No, it will be empty at the outset, if you are using a current version of Android Studio. The tutorial that you are following is rather old and out of date, and so its instructions will not line up with what you will see in Android Studio.

A new Android Studio project, particularly one created with the so-called "Blank Activity" template, will have an empty `res/drawable/` directory. The launcher icons are `mipmap` resources nowadays, so you will see a series of `res/mipmap.../` directories with `ic_launcher.png` files in them.
Icons — other than launcher icons — usually go in the `res/drawable.../` directories, but your starter project has no such icons, so Android Studio did not create them. However, if you use the Image Asset tool in Android Studio to create action bar icons, the tool will create the directories for you. Or, you can create the directories yourself, by right-clicking over `res/` and choosing to create a new resource directory.